# How to highlight parts of list items in a react built list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My list component should be able to highlight why a certain element is part of the list based on keywords entered by the user.

I am using the `react-highlighter` component currently inside the list item, but it requires me to send down the keyword entered by the user from the `search box => to the listview => to the list item`

That doesn't look very `react` to me.
I am also using `redux` so I have only one store, and the listview and items are not directly aware of the store. They are dumb components just rendering properties.

```
<SearchBox onChange={setSearchText} value={searchText} />
<List items={item} highlight={searchText}>
  <ListItem>
    <Highlight search={searchText}>{name}</Highlight>
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle such highlighting?

Comment: Passing properties down the tree seems very react to me. What sort of solution are you looking for?

Comment: it just feels the components get cluttered with props. Not sure, maybe something like a wrapper higher up the hierarchy that performs the highlighting

Comment: You can also consider the jsx span to reduce clutter.

Comment: You mean splash, @Mark?

Comment: I meant spread. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in a comment you could pull up your highlight functionality into a `HighlightedListItem` component.

```
<SearchBox onChange={setSearchText} value={searchText} />
<List items={item} >
  <HighlightedListItem item={item} highlight={searchText}>
    {...stuff}
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

In addition when thinking ahead to maximizing performance, this approach might be easier to reason when adding a `shouldcomponentupdate`

EX:

```
// HighlightedListItem
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.item !== this.props.item ||
         nextProps.searchText !== this.props.searchText;
}
```